# Existe alguma maneira de adicionar regras css pelo javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Se eu tenho a seguinte tag `style`:

```
<style>
 body{
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

Seria possível adicionar mais  uma nova regra de css como dentro desse `style` através do `Javascript`?

Por exemplo, quero adicionar isso ao final do primeiro `style` que dei como exemplo:

```
.class-x {
     color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Da pra fazer usando um append do jQuery, não? Meio trash, mas funciona

Comment: Teoricamente, você pode usar [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) mas provavelmente tem um jeito mais prático (com hierarquia de CSS, talvez) de fazer o que você quer. Dá pra explicar melhor qual o objetivo? Ou é só curiosidade?

Comment: Qual o objetivo? Tem algum exemplo que necessite dessa logica?

Comment: @Gabe curiosidade. Alguns não vêem utilidade, mas não é questão de ser útil. Só quero aprender mesmo se tem uma forma. Depois desse comentário alguém deve querer me dar negativos :)

Comment: Obrigado @Gabe! Achei isso aqui na referência que você mandou https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Eu nunca usei, então não posso dizer exatamente o que é possível fazer ou não. Mas acredito que `dcument.styleSheets` seja realmente o caminho...

Comment: Seria isso: 

var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
 
for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.opacity = 0;
}

Comment: Não é isso @durtto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O @Gabe deu uma [referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) na qual, depois de testado, comprovei que funciona (pelo menos no Google Chrome 46).

É através do método `insertRule`, presente em `CSSStyleSheet`.

Para acessá-lo, você deve acessar a lista de elementos `style` da página.

Nesse caso vou pegar o primeiro:

```
var css = document.styleSheets[0]
```

Em seguida inserimos a regra nesse `style`:

```
css.insertRule('body{ color: green; }', 0);
```

Comment: a algum tempo atrás, fiz uso do [css.js](https://github.com/radmen/css.js), se você estudar o código fonte dele, você verá que ele faz uso pesado deste recurso.